# Websocket callback not updating when figwheel reloads

Tags: websocket, clojurescript, figwheel

I have code that looks something like the below:

```
(defn on-message [event]
  (do-stuff))

(defn build-websocket []
  (let [ws (js.window.WebSocket. "ws://localhost:8888/ws/")]
    (set! (.-onopen ws) on-open)
    (set! (.-onclose ws) on-close)
    (set! (.-onerror ws) on-error)
    (set! (.-onmessage ws) on-message)
    ws))
```

I'm using [`figwheel`](https://github.com/bhauman/lein-figwheel). I have noticed that when I change my callbacks (`on-message`, `on-error`, etc), the app does reload, but old versions of these functions still get called.

```
(defn on-message [event]
  ; Changed. Requires hard reload to be called on websocket message.
  (do-other-stuff))
```

I understand that this is because the old version of the function is still referenced by the websocket.

Is there a pattern that would make this code reloadable? Perhaps I should be using `core/async`? If so, what would that look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps your code is not *reloadable*. Another thing to look at, for quick fix, is to always reload the namespace when you save from your editor/IDE:

```
(ns ^:figwheel-always my.namespace
  (:require [clojure.string :as str])
```

Notice the `^:figwheel-always` metadata.

For more on writing *reloadable* code see [here](https://github.com/bhauman/lein-figwheel#writing-reloadable-code).

Comment: I think you're right, non-"reloadable" code is exactly the issue. Thank you for the link and terminology, I've updated the question, and will research reloadable code.